# python : How to return from function in sub if statment?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
 def func(self,e):
    if x>0:
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, "are you sure?", 'Warning!', wx.OK | wx.CANCEL| wx.ICON_WARNING)
        result=dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        if result== wx.CANCEL:
            return
    win = FRMPOP(parent,data)
```

My question is on:

```
if result== wx.CANCEL:
    return
```

this if statement is a sub statement of `if x>0` I intended that the `return` will get out of `func1` but instead it doesn't and `FRMPOP` is being called. it looks like the `return` statement is just existing the `if x>0`.
Is there a way to change the `if result== wx.CANCEL` so it will exit from `func`? I know I can do that with flags.

Something like:

```
flag=0
 ...
    if result== wx.CANCEL:
        flag=1
if flag==0:
    win = FRMPOP(parent,data)
```

but i'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic / Stylish way to do that. I tried `break` and `continue` but I have no loop here so it wont accept them.

Comment: can you show how you are calling the function? which params you are passing in?

Comment: The `return` statement **will** exit the function if the condition `result==wx.CANCEL` is fulfilled. You should make sure that this is really the case.

Comment: `if x>0:`, i am not strong in python, so a basic question, where is this `x` coming from?? i see `e` passed to the function, not x!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wx.CANCEL` is not something that will be returned from [`ShowModal()`](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/MessageDialog.html#MessageDialog.ShowModal):

> Shows the dialog, returning one of ID_OK, ID_CANCEL, ID_YES, ID_NO or
>   ID_HELP.

So, you need `result == wx.ID_CANCEL`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following kind of logic:

```
def func(self,e):
    result = wx.ID_OK

    if x > 0:
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent, "are you sure?", 'Warning!', wx.OK | wx.CANCEL| wx.ICON_WARNING)
        result=dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    if result == wx.ID_OK:
        win = FRMPOP(parent,data)
```

Reducing the number of places a function returns tends to make the flow easier to read. Also I am assuming you would only want to run the function if OK is pressed, so it would be better not to check for `ID_CANCEL`.

I am guessing your return statement is never being called, as it would definitely have terminated the function.